# Visual Studio Community 2015 installation error

Tags: asp.net, windows, visual-studio, c#-4.0

I am always facing this error while installing VS 2015 Community Edition. I tried everything including updates, IE 11 installation but no result. Please help.[Here is the error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/glCJm.png)

Comment: Examine the log files as indicated.  Install support is here https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/home?forum=vssetup

Comment: If you *"tried everything"*, and nothing worked for you, then logic requires, that this problem has no solution.